# How can I export and print gitlab ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} var into my php project

Tags: php, docker, variables, gitlab

I have a drupal, dockerized, gitlab sources managed project (conf not done by myself) and I would like to export gitlab ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} variable through docker so that I can access and print it with php.

The complete CI/CD is based on 4 environments : local (each developper), integration, preprod and prod.

In .gitlab-ci.yml I found some variables definition for integration preprod and prod environment, but nothing for local.
i have (example for inte) :

```
.inte_env_project:
    variables:
        PROJECT_VERSION: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
```

And in one of the build scripts I have :
`replace_proj ./src/www/themes/ "'local';" "'${PROJECT_VERSION}';"`
From what I understood, for integration, preprod and prod envrionment, the PROJECT_VERSION variable takes from .gitlab-ci.yml file the CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME and then this script replace 'local' string in the code by the actual PROJECT_VERSION string.

Basically, I would like this functionnality as well for local environment :

- or by finding how to include variable definition for local environment in my .gitlab-ci.yml file
- or by exporting gitlab CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME variable to php

1/ I tried creating

```
.local_env_project
    variables:
        PROJECT_VERSION: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
```

but it seems not to be taken by the system

2/ I tried to add variables into local.yml conf file (example in docker web definition)

```
services:
    web:
        environment:
            NAME: 'value'
```

I can see the variable if I printenv in the docker console, but I don't find if I can, how to access it in php

3/ I tried same thing than 2 for other containers like php or bin, which create a var in each container environment but still cannot access it with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i used git post-checkout hooks to push HEAD file into my docker. Then I checked for the file and extract branch from the string